# How to Query a closure table with repeated nodes for paths?

Tags: mysql, sql, tree

One very efficient way of storing hierarchies in SQL is by using some kind of 'closure table'. 
It's a bit more difficult to edit and uses up more space, but can usually recursively be travelled with a single JOIN or a single query if you are only interested in IDs.

This table would contain 1 record for every possible ancestor/descendant relationship, as well as 1 record per item in the real table for which `anc=des=id` holds.

For this tree:

```
                 1
     2           4             7
   3   5        6
```

Our SQL table would contain:

```
+-----+-----+------+-------+
| anc | des | diff | depth |
+-----+-----+------+-------+
|   1 |   1 |    0 |     0 |
|   1 |   2 |    1 |     0 |
|   2 |   3 |    1 |     1 |
|   1 |   3 |    2 |     0 |
|   1 |   4 |    1 |     0 |
|   2 |   5 |    1 |     1 |
|   1 |   5 |    2 |     0 |
|   4 |   6 |    1 |     1 |
|   1 |   6 |    2 |     0 |
|   1 |   7 |    1 |     0 |
|   2 |   2 |    0 |     1 |
|   3 |   3 |    0 |     2 |
|   4 |   4 |    0 |     1 |
|   5 |   5 |    0 |     2 |
|   6 |   6 |    0 |     2 |
|   7 |   7 |    0 |     1 |
+-----+-----+------+-------+
```

Then the task: "Get all ancestors of node 5", in other words, the 'path to node 5' can be done with the following query:

```
SELECT `anc` FROM `closure` WHERE `des` = 5
```

And the task "Get all descendants of node 1" can be done with this query:

```
SELECT `des` FROM `closure` WHERE `anc` = 1
```

While "Get all direct descendants of node 1" is done like so:

```
SELECT `des` FROM `closure` WHERE `diff` = 1 AND `anc` = 1
```

Finally, "Get all root nodes" is done like this:

```
SELECT `anc` FROM `closure` WHERE `depth` = 0 AND `anc` = `des`
```

These four tasks together form the most utilized ways of selecting things from the tree. 
However, in reality, when categorizing things, people can't decide where to put things. Inevitably, something is required to end up in multiple places in the tree. This throws a spanner in the works; two of these naïve queries no longer work (N<sup>o</sup> 1 and N<sup>o</sup> 2).

Note that, in order to prevent problems with stack overflow and recursion, it is true in the example that our graph remains a kind of 'tree'; there are no cycles in it.

The first problem is that "Get all descendants" now has duplicate results. This can be fixed with a `GROUP BY` clause.

The second, harder, for me unsolved problem is the 1<sup>st</sup> question: there are now multiple possible paths to a leaf node. Let's split the question into two possible satisfactory results:

Is there a way, using a single or fixed number of JOINs in a single or fixed number of queries, for an arbitrarily deep tree, to get either:

**The Canonical path**

This is the path with the least number of nodes leftmost in the tree representation to a specific leaf node. Note that it is not necessarily true that the tree is 'sorted' like the example in the data structure, as nodes are arbitrarily inserted and removed.

**All paths**

Gets all possible paths to a specific leaf node.

*An illustrative example of why the naïve method fails*:

Consider this tree:

```
       1
     2   3
     5   4
     6   6
```

Asking the question "What are the ascendants of 6" should have two logical answers:

1-2-5-6 and 1-3-4-6.

Yet, using the naïve query and sorting, we can only really get:

1-2-4-6 or 1-3-5-6.

Which are both not actually valid paths.

In all of the tutorials about closure tables I've read, it's plainly stated that closure tables are capable of handling hierarchies where the same item appears in multiple places, but it's never actually explained how to properly do this, just 'left to the reader'. I run into nontrivial problems trying to, however.